# How to download to the war file from JBOSS Server

Tags: java, jboss, server, web-deployment

I had Deployed to the java Project using on  JBOSS Server , But i had lost on my All Source Code Currently, i don't have any of my code,I Don't know what i do ,I have a small request for If any chance to get and download for the war file from JBOSS Server If any possibility Can you please tell me...

Comment: If Any one know the answer Can you please tell me..

Answer (score 0):

Go to jboss server folder and standalone folder and go to deployments